# py2exe: Scapy, 'no such file or directory: packet'

Tags: python, py2exe, scapy

I want to use py2exe to convert a python script to exe but it displays the following upon execution:

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
*** finding dlls needed ***
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'packet'
```

I then removed all the code until I found that it was caused by "from scapy.all import *". I tried reinstalling Scapy and only importing different modules, the error still appeared.

Comment: Are you on python2 or python3?

Comment: python 2.7 @EriksDobelis